# How can I combine two classes with common members into a single input?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, composition

I need to create a service that takes 3 inputs, which basically boils down to `A`, `B`, and a combination of `A` and `B` which we will call `C`.

Suppose these classes are defined as follows:

```
public abstract class InputBase
{
  public bool Option1 { get; set; }
  public decimal Rate { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class A : InputBase
{
  public decimal Fee { get; set; }
}

public class B : InputBase
{
  public decimal Fee { get; set; }
}
```

The `Fee`s in `A` and `B` are distinct and separate and can be different, for cases like `C` where you can do a combination of `A` and `B` together in the same request.

We currently just have a class that looks like this:

```
public class C
{
  public A A { get; set; }
  public B B { get; set; }
}
```

However, this makes it extremely annoying to update any values that are common in both. For example:

```
var c = new C
{
  A = new A(),
  B = new B()
}

//this is ugly and what we want to avoid
c.A.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
c.B.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
```

We'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
c.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
//later
var createdDate = c.A.DateCreated; //points to date created before
```

The naive way of doing this would be to implement setters that go and update both inner classes with the value, but then what do we do with the getters?

Also, should `C` inherit from `InputBase`, since it is technically an input to the service?

What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: You are asking to keep separate instances but want them combined into a single instance. Is `Fee` the only field with a different or are there other things in the objects that make them different?

Comment: There are other things, I just used a single field to keep it concise.

Comment: I sense a strong code smell on your design. If you want to send `A` and `B` together, you should be sending an `IEnumerable<InputBase>`. How you manipulate them together if some properties need to have the same value is a different concern and could be addressed with a helper class exposing methods suchs as `AddInputBase` and `SetDateCreated`.

Comment: `A` and `B` are both settable and so are their `DateCreated` properties, which means you can't keep their `DateCreated` properties in sync. You could set them both at the same time as suggested in an answer, but either one could be changed independently or replaced with another instance. It seems odd to try to ensure that they're in sync when you really can't.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks. That question just seemed like a homework question where no effort was given. You're right I shouldn't have voted it as requiring editing. I don't know what the correct way to handle such cases is.

Answer (score 3):

There are certain concerns about your inheritance structure. I don't disagree with other answers, but I feel that they've gotten distracted with these tangential elements.

I'm trying to only answer your direct question, which you already answered yourself:

> The naive way of doing this would be to implement setters that go and update both inner classes with the value, but then what do we do with the getters?

You're correct about the getter issue, but keep in mind that the getter is not required to exist. You can have write-only properties. They are rare, but they have a purpose.

I'm also not sure what exactly is *naive* about it. Simple solutions are not bad. If anything, simple solutions are better than complex ones, if they manage to fix the same problem. [**KISS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) applies:

> *The KISS principle states that most systems work best if they are kept simple rather than made complicated; therefore simplicity should be a key goal in design and **unnecessary** complexity should be avoided.*

Notice the emphasis on **unnecessary** complexity. If it's necessary, then it (by definition) serves a purpose.

---

```
var c = new C
{
  A = new A(),
  B = new B()
}

//this is ugly and what we want to avoid
c.A.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
c.B.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
```

A simple fix is to make a custom property in `C`:

```
public class C
{
    public DateTime DateCreated 
    {
        set
        {
            this.A.DateCreated = value;
            this.B.DateCreated = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I omitted the getter because it wouldn't make much sense (would you display `A.CreatedOn` or `B.CreatedOn`)?
But it's not wrong to simply omit the getter, so that seems like the best approach here.

This creates the behavior you want:

```
//sets both values
c.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
```

However, values are retrieved separately:

```
var createdDateA = c.A.DateCreated;
var createdDateB = c.B.DateCreated;
```

---

> The naive way of doing this would be to implement setters that go and update both inner classes with the value, but then what do we do with the getters?

Besides my earlier feedback on this, if you're really averse to writeonly properties, you can basically convert them into a method. Functionally equivalent, but more explicitly doesn't expose a get method:

```
public class C
{
    public void SetDateCreated(DateTime value)
    {
        this.A.DateCreated = value;
        this.B.DateCreated = value;
    }
}
```

---

> Also, should C inherit from InputBase, since it is technically an input to the service?

Not unless C has its own `Fee` object which works exactly as the other derived `InputBase` classes.

This question is a bit broad; it hinges on the inheritance (and SOLID) concerns in your codebase. This is too big for a StackOverflow question. If you can rephrase this to a concrete question about the inheritance sturcture, it might be better suited to SoftwareEngineering.SE (or possibly CodeReview.SE, if you have working code).

Answer (score 0):

You could make C derive from InputBase, as well as have a collection of InputBase.

```
public class C : InputBase, IHaveInputBase
{
    IList<InputBase> IHaveInputBase.Inputs { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public void Handle(InputBase inputBase)
    {
        IHaveInputBase haveInputBase = inputBase as IHaveInputBase;

        if (haveInputBase != null)
        {
            foreach (InputBase input in haveInputBase.Inputs) 
            {
                this.Handle(input);
            }
        }

        inputBase.DateCreated = this.dateTimeService.UtcNow();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of not being able to do `C.DateCreated = DateTime.Now` though.

Comment: Because he has stated he needs additional logic to manipulate the "children".

Comment: Didn't this post rather mean to read: public class C : IList<InputBase> { } (or something approximately like that?

Comment: @Logan - only if C needs DateCreated. If it does, and it really does need to be InputBase, then you could derive from it, and handle it differently. I updated my answer.

Comment: @JuanR - I believe my original answer did that. I've updated it anyway to make it more clear.

Comment: @TTT - I said it C could be, or have a colleciton of inputbase. I left it open to either.

Answer (score 0):

I might not have understood you correctly, but why don't you make `C` inherit from `InputBase` and have an `AFee` and `BFee`:

```
class C: InputBase {
    public decimal AFee { get; set; }
    public decimal BFee { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could add constructors for `C` that takes an `A` and a `B`. This will check whether they have the same `Option1`, `Rate` and `DateCreated`. If they do, assign the `C` fields with their values. If they don't, throw an exception or something like that.

You could also have methods like `GetA` or `GetB` that creates `A` and `B` objects from `C`'s values.

```
class C : InputBase {
    public decimal AFee { get; set; }
    public decimal BFee { get; set; }

    public C(A a, B b) {
        if (a.DateCreated == b.DateCreated && a.Option1 == b.Option1 && a.Rate == b.Rate) {
            Option1 = a.Option1;
            Rate = a.Rate;
            DateCreated = a.DateCreated;
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException("...");
        }
    }

    public C() {}

    public A GetA() {
        return new A { DateCreated = DateCreated, Option1 = Option1, Rate = Rate, Fee = AFee };
    }

    public B GetB() {
        return new B { DateCreated = DateCreated, Option1 = Option1, Rate = Rate, Fee = BFee };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You could use method for update input which takes action

```
public class C 
{
    public A A { get; }
    public B B { get; }

    public void UpdateInput(Action<InputBase> updateFunc)
    {
        updateFunc(A);
        updateFunc(B);
    }
}
```

And then just update any of your InputBase properties through Action.

```
var c = new C
{
  A = new A(),
  B = new B()
}
var dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
c.UpdateInput(input => input.DateCreated = dateTime);
```

**2.** Or you could make properties of InputBase virtual and override them like this

```
public abstract class InputBase
{
    public virtual bool Option1 { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class C : InputBase
{
    private bool _option1;
    public override bool Option1
    {
        get => _option1;
        set
        {
            _option1 = value;
            A.Option1 = value;
            B.Option1 = value;
        }
    }

    private decimal _rate;
    public override decimal Rate
    {
        get => _rate;
        set
        {
            _rate = value;
            A.Rate = value;
            B.Rate = value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime _dateCreated;
    public override DateTime DateCreated
    {
        get => _dateCreated;
        set
        {
            _dateCreated = value;
            A.DateCreated = value;
            B.DateCreated = value;
        }
    }

    public A A { get; }
    public B B { get; }
}
```